# Find if any array entry matches an object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array:

```
 arr=[
      "EMPRESA",
      "CD_DIRECAO",
      "DT_INI_DIRECAO"
    ]
```

I have an object:

```
primary = {
           "EMPRESA": {"type": "varchar"},
           "CD_DIRECAO": {"type": "varchar"},
           "DT_INI_DIRECAO": {"type": "date"},
           "CD_DEPT": {"type": "varchar"},
           "DT_INI_DEPT": {"type": "date"},
           "ANO": {"type": "number"},
           "MES": {"type": "number"},
           "TP_CUSTO": {"type": "varchar"},
          }
```

I need to check if at least one element of arr exists in primary.
Apreciate your help.

Comment: lodash: `_.intersection(arr, _.keys(primary)).length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check if the key exist.

```js
var arr = ["EMPRESA", "CD_DIRECAO", "DT_INI_DIRECAO"],
    primary = { EMPRESA: { type: "varchar"}, CD_DIRECAO: { type: "varchar"}, DT_INI_DIRECAO: { type: "date"}, CD_DEPT: { type : "varchar"}, DT_INI_DEPT: { type: "date"}, ANO: { type: "number"},  MES: { type: "number"}, TP_CUSTO: { type: "varchar"}},
    contain = arr.some(function (k) {
        return k in primary;
    });

console.log(contain);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the keys of object and check if exits using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
for (property in primary){
       if (arr.indexOf(property) !== -1)
         console.log("Exists");
 };
```

With [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(primary, function(key){
    if (arr.indexOf(key) !== -1)
        console.log("Exists"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if (primary[arr[i]]){
        //exists
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var arr=["EMPRESA","CD_DIRECAO","DT_INI_DIRECAO"];
var primary={EMPRESA:{type:"varchar"},CD_DIRECAO:{type:"varchar"},DT_INI_DIRECAO:{type:"date"},CD_DEPT:{type:"varchar"},DT_INI_DEPT:{type:"date"},ANO:{type:"number"},MES:{type:"number"},TP_CUSTO:{type:"varchar"}};

var result = arr.some(function(element){
   return primary[element];
});

console.log(result);
```